# Is it possible to -webkit-filter: invert(); everything but images and videos

Tags: css

I'm currently using the code below to change invert the color of everything on a page, this is undesirable as the pictures and videos are also inverted.

```
html {
    -webkit-filter: invert() hue-rotate(180deg) brightness(105%) contrast(105%);
}
```

I'm wondering if it's possible to filter everything excluding images and videos? This is all pretty new to me there probably is an obvious answer, but I can't think of it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this [demo](http://codepen.io/vilaskumkar/pen/vEMyWL)

```
  iframe, img, html {
      -webkit-filter: invert() hue-rotate(180deg) brightness(105%) contrast(105%);
  }
```